# Android app not running on specified api version + bug

Tags: java, android, android-studio

We developed an Android app targetting latest sdk versions: `22 Lollipop`, but when we shipped out app to test users they said that they couldn't install it on android 5.1 because Google Play didn't allow it. It is saying `your device/android version is not supported.`
The place to define that is in the Gradle Build and Manifest file which both of the set to 22. I don't have any idea how to solve it. Can you help me?

p.s I have a bug with Android studio and I thought may be it related to this,
Once I updated to `1.2Preview` version, I lost the design view for layout, in details, it shows rendering and the layout in some activities, but it pop ups that `Rendering Problems, following file not found...`, But it was working before update and the libraries it is declaring that missed are in their own place.
Today Android studio 1.2 released completely but my problem didn't solve yet.

**Update 1:**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "cc.dd.tt"
    minSdkVersion 12
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-com.twitter.sdk.android.twitter.txt'
    }
}
}
```

Comment: could you please add the piece of your build.gradle when when you are declaring minSdkVersion, TargetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion?

Comment: this is maybe not related but there is something specific you want to do that can't be done in 5.0 but only in 5.1?

Comment: I'm using toolbar, using support library for pre-lollipop, but it's also possible in 5.0.

Comment: But api 21 (Android 5.0) is lolipop and support toolbar and all that stuff.

Comment: Have you also ensured that there aren't conflicting tags in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file? Perhaps you specified `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="X" android:targetSdkVersion="Y"/>` where `X` and `Y` conflict with the values in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @willis First of all, they were the same and problem existed. 2nd, android studio itself tells that the values in manifest will be overwritten by the gradle values. so it can't be cause of the problem. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Hamed MP Have you solve this issue? I have same Problem. If problem is solved please update it.